# Why is Zina compared to murder and other major sins?

Tags: punishment, zina, world

[What is greater sin between murder and zina?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40335/what-is-greater-sin-between-murder-and-zina)

Looking at this answer you can see Zina is a major sin as it is compared to the likes of murder. However, I cant understand why.

https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-5988635/Every-murder-costs-nation-3-2million-research-shows.html

Murder destroys families, relationships, takes life of innocents, is really expensive and the list just goes on.
Some may say the same about Zina but it doesnt cost nearly as much, there are rarely unwanted children and even so it doesnt cost society as much either. Also there are lots of contraceptives and even if there is unwanted pregnancies many can get abortions. This altogether still doesnt have nearly as bad as an impact as murder

https://www.bostonglobe.com/ideas/2013/03/03/which-religions-have-most-premarital-sex/whTrXNlukf5nFRk9UlZ64I/story.html

Such a large amount of Muslims are having sex before marriage these statistics exclude illegal sexual intercourse within marriage. This number is increasing

---(And the servants of the Beneficent) are those who do not invoke another god with Allah, and who do not…commit fornication/adultery, for whoever does that shall receive the penalty; for him shall the torment be doubled on the day of resurrection, and therein he shall abide forever, disgraced, save him who repents and believes and does good works; those, Allah shall change their misdeeds into good works. And Allah is Forgiving, Compassionate) (Al-Furqan: 68-70).

---“There are three types of sinners that Allah will not speak to on the Day of Resurrection; neither He will purify them nor will He even look at them; rather they will suffer severe punishment: an older person who commits adultery, a king or ruler who lies to his subjects, and a poor person who acts arrogantly!” (Muslim and An-Nasa’i)

---The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said, “O mankind! Beware of fornication/adultery for it entails six dire consequences: three of them relating to this world and three to the next world. As for the three that are related to this world, they are the following: it removes the glow of one’s face, brings poverty, and reduces the life-span. As for its dire consequences in the next world they are: it brings down the wrath of Allah upon the person, subjects him to terrible reckoning, and finally casts him in hell-fire” (Al-Bayhaqi).

These are examples which show that Zina is comparable to acts such as murder or at least the punishment is supposed to be. This means that majority of the population would be in hell eternally. Some may say that Muslims may ask for forgiveness but what about the others not to mention not all of Muslims will ask for forgiveness, some dont care and some dont even know.

Why is Zina compared to murder when in this world it has such less impacts and quite a lot of times (from experience with communciating with others etc) it doesnt have any bad impacts?

Answer (score 1):

Zina is by far the most selfish form of betrayal. It destroys families, psychologically, emotionally, physically and spiritually. I was a victim of adultery courtesy of my Islamic wife. My children suffer from depression, anxiety and many emotional and psychological affects from her repeated adultery. I divorced her in the name of Allah and she is still engaging in Zina some 7 years later. My children still suffer till this very day and pray to Allah on a daily basis to remove the damage of Zina. Our trust has been damaged and we have been scarred emotionally. But I love this test. Its beautiful. Allah is everything, the most beautiful!! He is raising us in the ranks with this tough exam. We are victorious because though we are hurting we never lost faith in Allah. This life is temporary, fleeting. If someone commits adultery that is their own spiritual suicide if they refuse to repent to Allah.It hurts but you suffer the pain for the sake of Allah.He wipes away your sins as you suffer as a soldier in Islam, still doing righteous deeds. My sons and I have become better muslims due to this adversity. I give my undying loyalty to Allah. HE WILL NEVER CHANGE!!Allah told IBLIS to bow to Adam for a reason. We are stronger and submit our will to Allah by our own free will. Shaytan is a coward. He is powerless. he wants to distract you from Allah! I took my wife's adultery as a symbol of honor from Allah. I stayed true to Allah. My sons stayed true to Allah. Allah is the only Love that matters. Fight in the name of Allah the rejected Shaytan by PRAISING ALLAH MORE WHEN ADVERSITY STRIKES..BEG Allah for forgiveness and don't let anything stop you in the pursuit of righteousness! What you need is Allahs love and mercy! Shaytan has no power over the believers. Nothing happens but by Allahs will!! So if something befalls you such as adultery it was not going to miss you. Love Allah more!!! praise him MORE!! He will never betray you as your spouse has..ever!!Any spouse who has committed zina run back to Allah!! He loves those who asks for forgiveness. Do not be a loyal fornicator/adulterers in companionship with Shaytan!!! you committed the act while you were low in faith and discipline. Make tahhajud prayer and asks for forgiveness and stay away from acts that will lead to adultery. Alhamdulillah...Allahuakbar..Subhanna Allah....THE TEACHER IS ALWAYS QUIET WHILE THE STUDENT IS BEING TESTED..MAY ALLAH HAVE MERCY ON US ALL...

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion is due to not understanding what the standard of morality is. Not everything is only related to something materiel in this world.

Zina is one of the worst sins because it shows an extreme lack of loyalty, extreme disobedience to God, extreme lack of shame, and extreme lack of respect for the human relationships Allah created.

And it is one of the worst sins because it creates corruption, enmity, and hatred between people. This is not to even mention the risk of children outside of marriage. And making children outside of marriage is itself such an evil that if an action leads to it happening even just 0.1% of the time, that action is evil and must be avoided.

Although Zina is not worse than murder, one aspect to look at is that murder may separate families for the short time of this world. But, Zina can actually destroy them forever.

But, all that is irrelevant. As Muslims, we must realize that Allah knows better what is bad and what is good. Any reasons we make are only guesses, and in fact, Allah has no responsibility to tell us the reasons.

Comment: But look at the links I have mentioned about murder. Zina doesnt have nearly as bad of an impact and yes it may be disobedient but why is it not moral, why is it wrong, what makes it so bad that it is compared to murder and the likes? Also something that we are assuming is that of those born to unwanted pregnancies before marriage that the babies are not aborted or they live in bad conditions. Do you have any evidence to disprove/prove this.

Comment: Also since lots of Muslims and non-Muslims alike engage in Zina that means they are going to hell because of the hadith/verses above. Yes some may ask for forgiveness but often lots dont or dont even know/care not to mention the non-Muslims too. Lots of the population will be going to hell because of something that didnt really have that big of an impact in the worldy life so if it didnt have that big of an impact (and to some it may actually bring joy or happiness) of course they wouldnt think bad of it.

Comment: @AAAAAOOOOO Murder is worse than Zina, that is true. No one disputes that. However, Zina does have worse impact than any other sin short of Shirk and murder as I mentioned in my answer, and you are only perhaps considering material impact.

How many Muslims or non-Muslims do something makes no difference to it being evil and despicable. Zina is the more alluring thus more deadly sin than murder because it does give people temporary pleasure. If they do it and do not repent, let them taste the punishment for it or Allah may forgive them.

Comment: Yes but then that means a lot of the population is going to be punished for a sin they didnt think much of because either they didnt know or it was so widely accepted that they thought nothing of it. Also what about robbery, torture, alcohol etc. These all have a significantly greater impact on the well being of people but why is Zina the one mentioned? Also as I said before the main things people mention of the worldy impacts is unwanted pregnancies and STD's however there are contraceptives etc and people do abortions not to mention the children who are raised well despite being unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

May Allah help us to stay away from these sins. Zina, on the surface, may appear alluring as there is pleasure associated with it. But there are many bad consequences associated with this act both at the personal level as well as the societal level. We cannot always quantify the impact sin has on us inwardly as it is a spiritual matter. On a societal level, the result of zina leads to broken homes, unwanted pregnancies, many kinds of diseases, the lack of trust between people, jealousies which lead to many conflicts, and a host of other problems. You may wish to refer to this article for more information: https://muslimvillage.com/2017/12/31/127241/consequences-haram-sex/

Allah knows best.